# Is there a way to run VBScript as a command-line argument rather than a file?

Tags: vbscript, command-line-arguments, wsh

Say you have a very simple one-liner VBScript command you need to run, something like getting the day of the month for yesterday:

```
wscript.echo day(date()-1)
```

At the moment, I have to either have a separate `.vbs` file and then run it with:

```
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo myscript.vbs') do set dd=%%a
```

or, if I don't want to maintain the script separately:

```
echo wscript.echo day(date()-1) >temp.vbs
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo temp.vbs') do set dd=%%a
del /s temp.vbs >nul: 2>nul:
```

Now I don't *mind* the hideous `for` statement to capture the output, I'd just like to know if there's a way to avoid having to either maintain a separate VBScript file, or create and destroy one on the fly.

Something like:

```
cscript //nologo //exec wscript.echo day(date()-1)
```

would be ideal, but I know `cscript` doesn't support this.

Is there any way to achieve this, keeping in mind I want to capture its output into a variable from a `cmd` script?

Comment: You'll be lucky! This is Windows! I too wait with baited breath :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write **one** script that echoes the [Eval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)'ed argument(s):

```
WScript.Echo Eval(WScript.Arguments(0))
```

or **one** script that echoes the result of a computation specified by its (first) argument:

```
Select Case WScript.Aruments(0)
  Case "prevday"
    wscript.echo day(date()-1)
  Case "answer"
    WScript.Echo 4711
  ...
```